# How to create a new route when a user submits a form?

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I am still new to Node and Express, and I've tried Googling this but perhaps I just need to know what to Google.

A big part of my app involves letting users create their own profile, which comes from a simple form submission. How would I go about taking what they've submitted in a form and putting that on a live page of my site?

Is there a middleware that I should be using for that? Is there a term I should Google? I just need to know how to get started and then I can figure the rest out from there. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You don't create a new route, you have a parameter within a route that allows information to be provided (e.g. `.../profile/<user name>`). I suggest running through some introductory documentation/tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, I certainly will.

Comment: Please add releavant script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicest way to do this is to set up a route with parameter. That way if user goes to `/user/Jake` he will see his profile. Like this: https://nimble-beetle.hyperdev.space/user/Jake

Check it out here: https://hyperdev.com/#!/project/nimble-beetle

```
app.get("/user/:username", function (request, response) {
    response.send('thank you for registering, ' + request.params.username);
});
```

All you need to do is grab the username, fetch user's data and display his profile.

Answer (score -1):

you are probably looking for the `body-parser` Middleware:
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

This one is decoding content of your request, it can decode Form data and JSON, depending how you send the data in your request, and gives you a JSON object.